# I have a problem with articles/ is it an appointment or the appointment when I am talking about a specific one with a person to whom it concerns

Tags: articles

Could you please help me! I am never sure which article I should use. I know the basic rules etc. but still always doubt whether an article I used is correct or not.
For instance: "I've got **A** house viewing appointment with you or I've got **THE** house viewing appointment with you. As far as I understand it should be ''the'' since I am talking about one specific appointment? I would be very grateful for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised that you're not clear: it is difficult.

I would say that the criterion for using the definite article is more than whether you're talking about "one specific appointment": normally it's also that you expect the other party to know which specific one you're talking about.

That is why very often the first time something is mentioned in a discussion it will be "a", and only "the" thereafter, once it has been brought into the conversation. If you start a conversation with *I saw a friend of yours the other day*, then you're certainly talking about a specific person, but at that point you don't expect the other person to know who you saw, so it's *a*.

However, in this case, even though you presumably do expect the other party to know which appointment you are talking about, you would still most often use "an appointment" at the beginning: "I have an appointment to view your house at 2pm".

I'm not sure why this is. I think it is partly because *I have* acts as a sort of "presentative" - like a personal form of *there is* - and it is unusual to use "the" in presentatives, because their function is to bring a new topic into the conversation.

If, rather than this "presentative" you went straight in with talking about it, assuming they did know which appointment you meant, you could use "the" - *Can we talk about the appointment for me to view your house?* - but actually, there I think people would be more likely to use a possessive: *Can we talk about my appointment to view your house?*

Comment: Thank you for your prompt, clear and concise respond. I  really appreciate it!